# How do I find the maximum value in an array within a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

```
a                      b
loc.1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6]
loc.2  [3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 8, 6]
loc.3  [1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6]
...
```

I want to find the maximum of the array in column b and append this to the original data frame. My thought was something like this:

```
for line in df: 
    split = map(float,b.split(','))
    count_max = max(split)
print count
```

Ideal output should be:

```
a                      b           max_val
    loc.1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6]   7
    loc.2  [3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 8, 6]   8
    loc.3  [1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6]   8
    ...
```

But this does not work, as I cannot use b.split as it is not defined...

Comment: Instead of `b`, I think you should have `df.loc[, 'b']`.

Comment: pd.DataFrame(df['b'].values.tolist()).max(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If working with lists without `NaN`s best is use `max` in list comprehension or `map`:

```
a['max'] = [max(x) for x in a['b']]
```

---

```
a['max'] = list(map(max, a['b']))
```

Pure pandas solution:

```
a['max'] = pd.DataFrame(a['b'].values.tolist()).max(axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
array = {'loc.1': np.array([  1,2,3,4,7,5,6]),
         'loc.2': np.array([  3,4,3,7,7,8,6]),
         'loc.3': np.array([  1,4,3,1,7,8,6])}

L = [(k, v) for k, v in array.items()]
a = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['a','b']).set_index('a')

a['max'] = [max(x) for x in a['b']]
print (a)
                           b  max
a                                
loc.1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6]    7
loc.2  [3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 8, 6]    8
loc.3  [1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6]    8
```

EDIT:

You can also get `max` in `list comprehension`:

```
L = [(k, v, max(v)) for k, v in array.items()]
a = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['a','b', 'max']).set_index('a')

print (a)
                           b  max
a                                
loc.1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6]    7
loc.2  [3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 8, 6]    8
loc.3  [1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6]    8
```

Comment: @chrisz - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df["max_val"] = df["b"].apply(lambda x:max(x))
```

Comment: This works, but vectorised calculations should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` arrays for a vectorised calculation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['loc.1', 'loc.2', 'loc.3'],
                   'b': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6],
                         [3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 8, 6],
                         [1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6]]})

df['maxval'] = np.array(df['b'].values.tolist()).max(axis=1)

print(df)

#        a                      b  maxval
# 0  loc.1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6]       7
# 1  loc.2  [3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 8, 6]       8
# 2  loc.3  [1, 4, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6]       8
```